# need histogram from these results VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I need some help with the histogram. My program counted the words with three, four, five and six letters. Now I need to make simple histogram from the received answers. This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim tekst As String
    Dim rijec() As String
    Dim trazena As String
    Dim brojac1 As Integer = 1
    Dim brojac2 As Integer = 0
    Dim brojac3 As Integer = 0
    Private Sub btnUcitaj_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUcitaj.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnPrebroj1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrebroj1.Click

        tekst = RichTextBox1.Text
        rijec = tekst.Split(CChar(" "))
        Dim count = From x In rijec Where x.Length = 3
        txtTri.Text = ("Number of words: " & count.Count.ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrebroj2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrebroj2.Click
        tekst = RichTextBox1.Text
        rijec = tekst.Split(CChar(" "))
        Dim count = From x In rijec Where x.Length = 4
        txtCetiri.Text = ("Number of words: " & count.Count.ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrebroj3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrebroj3.Click
        tekst = RichTextBox1.Text
        rijec = tekst.Split(CChar(" "))
        Dim count = From x In rijec Where x.Length = 5
        txtPet.Text = ("Number of words: " & count.Count.ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrebroj4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrebroj4.Click
        tekst = RichTextBox1.Text
        rijec = tekst.Split(CChar(" "))
        Dim count = From x In rijec Where x.Length = 6
        txtSest.Text = ("Number of words: " & count.Count.ToString())
    End Sub
```

i need histogram from these results from picture.

[image]

Comment: again its **vb.net** not  **VBA**

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic actually has a control called a chart which is nice for this kind of situation. I found a tutorial [here](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/display-data-as-charts-and-graph-in-visual-basic.html) if you would like to check it out.
I wrote up this function that should work with your code, all you need to do is add a data chart and call it *Chart1* and call this function.

```
Private Sub ShowData()
    Chart1.Series.Clear() ' Delete the default data series.

    Dim tekst = RichTextBox1.Text
    Dim rijec = tekst.Split(CChar(" "))

    With Chart1.Series.Add("Word Lengths") ' Add a new series called Word Lengths

        For wordLength As Integer = 3 To 6 ' Check every word length from 3 to 6
            Dim count = From x In rijec Where x.Length = wordLength ' Count how many words there are
            .Points.AddXY(wordLength, count.Count) ' Add a new data point
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Good luck, I hope this helped!

---

~Nic